# how do i post textbox value which is dynamically created by jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

i am working with codeigniter framework i am trying to  use textboxes in HTML form when the user click the button a textbox will automatically generated by jquery but when i submit the form the other textbox values are posting correctly but i can't post the jquery textbox value.

here is the jquery code:

```
  $("#button").live('click',function add(){ 
   $("#tblRel").append(
       '<tr ><td>'
    +'<input type="text" class="input_value_short" id="prova" name="jquery_txt" value="prova" />'+ 
       '</td><tr>'
   );
});
```

HTML:

```
  <?php echo form_open("validation/form_main");?>
  <table id="tblRel"  border="0">
      <tr>
          <td class="lable">Applicant Name:</td>
          <td colspan="3"><?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'applicant_name','class'=>'input_value_long','value'=>set_value('applicant_name'))) ?></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
 <?php echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','name'=>'Save','value'=>'Save record','class'=>'button_print'));?>
```

in the form_main() function i am posting like this:

```
    form_main(){
    $name        = $this->input->post('applicant_name');
    $jquery_txt  = $this->input->post('jquery_txt');
    }
```

i can get the value of $name but the $jquery_txt is empty
can anyone help me please! and sorry form my poor english.

Comment: So where is table #tblRel in your page? Because the only thing I can think of that can go wrong is that you add the input field outside your <form></form> block

Comment: chek the name of the input you named it as `age` and get it in the `form_main` as `jquery_text`

Comment: Mr nagy i change that but it still empty result

Comment: can you try var_dump($_POST) inside the form_main function and tell me what's it outputting? Also, do you see the textfield in the table when you click on the button?

Comment: yes i can see the textfield when the button is clicked but in var_dump($_POST) i have the 'applicant_name' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: Check my solution, in your case what happened was, the form get submitted before the contents get appended since both were associated to the same button.

Answer (score 1):

```
      $("#button").live('click',function add(){ 
           $("#tblRel").append('<tr ><td><input type="text" class="input_value_short" id="jquery_txt" name="jquery_txt[]" value="prova" /></td><tr>');
       });
```

I guess your name and is are different for the textbox..Make it same and if you have more than  one textbox change the name of the textbox into array otherwise you will get only one value after posting it.

Comment: from which name do i post it?

Comment: That i have added in the answer.I have changed the name and id of your textbox into jquery_text

Comment: I don't think it is with the naming, it was on the order in which things took place. The submission happened before the content append. Check my solution, it worked for me =)

Comment: It is good idea.. I tried in your way. but, i'm getting only static element value in php. I could not get dynamic element values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the jQuery code to this, and it should work fine. Your problem was that you were adding the contents with the "submit" button's click, which would submit the form and the contents would get appended after the submit request.

```
<script>
    $("form").live('submit',function add(){ 
   $("#tblRel").append(
       '<tr ><td>'
    +'<input type="text" class="input_value_short" id="prova" name="jquery_txt" value="prova" />'+ 
       '</td><tr>'
   );
       return true;
});
</script>
```