# Dynamically created texbox does not post values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Why don't dynamically created textboxes using jQuery post values to the post method in the controller?

jQuery code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var curContactCount = $("#contactcount").val();

    $("#addContactButton").click(function () {
        if (parseInt(counter) + parseInt(curContactCount) >= 50) {
            alert("Only 50 Contacts allowed");
            return false;
        }

        var firstNameStr = 'NewContactList[' + counter + '].FirstName';
        var firstNameId = firstNameStr.replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_").replace(".", "_");

        var newTextBoxDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'NewContactGroup');

        newTextBoxDiv1.html(
   ' <div class="column-margin-20t20b">' +
       ' <div class="box">' +
           ' <div class="left">' +
                '<label for="' + firstNameId + '">First Name</label>' +
           ' </div>' +
           ' <div class="right">' +
               ' <input type="text" name="' + firstNameStr + '" id="' + firstNameId + '" value=""></input>' +
           ' </div>' +
       ' </div>' +
    ' </div>'
);

        newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#mainDivNewClient");
        counter++;
    });
});
```

Controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult AddNewClient(ClientViewModel clientToAdd, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> qString)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)..........
```

In clientToAdd, I am getting NewContactList as nulll. Why?

Comment: use **on or live** method of jquery like $("#addContactButton").on('click', function ()

Comment: hi u can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042164/how-do-i-post-textbox-value-which-is-dynamically-created-by-jquery

Comment: Do you have a form tag around the inputs you are submitting

Comment: Thank you all for reply. I tried all as follows:

1. Tried $("#addContactButton").on('click', function () but did not fix the issue. 
2. Went to link Suggested by Anil but I think in my case I am appending first then submitting the form so this does not seem to be the issue. 
3. My inputs do have form tag around them and I am posting screen print of how my code looks like when I do "inspect element". It does show <form> tags around. 

Friends: I have tried to debug this for 3 days..and pulling my hair.. Pl help! ![enter image description here][1]  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rGJrO.png

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the above code result in multiple divs with the same id of "NewContactGroup".

Update:
Ok, I might not be absolutely right about this but just trying to help. After looking at the image you provided I think the problem might be rooted in the way you are naming your input fields. I believe what you are trying to create is an object with the fields FirstName etc at every index. This probably isn't being interpreted by your Action Controller in the same way.

Since you only have one field(repeating), what you could do is something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
$("yourButton").click(function(){
  $("yourDiv").append("<input type='text' name='yourName'" + counter + " />");
  counter++;
});
```

And then in your ClientViewModel constructor:

```
public ClientViewModel(params string[] inputValues)
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Or, you could also in theory loop through the keys in the Request variable

```
public ClientViewModel()
{
   foreach(var key in Request.Form)
   {
      string yourString = Request.Form[key];
   }
}
```

This would get you all the string values that are posted, so you don't have to keep count.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Jeevan, You are correct that code does create multiple divs with NewContactGroup id. But if I am clicking addContactButton only one time then there is only one div with ID NewContactGroup. In that case I should see that record posting to clientToAdd. I do not get that. Attaching image for your reference.

Comment: actually has have about 10 fields repeating. FirstName is only one of them. Here for simplicity and also in my code to test the logic I am testing with only 1 field for now.